# Regex for multiple numbers input

Tags: java, regex

Im relatively new to this but im trying to do a regex which is in the format of multiple numbers ranging from 1-1000 eg:1 200 300 2 245

```
    public static final String PERSON_INDEX_VALIDATION_REGEX = "^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1000) +$";
```

However what I did above does not seem to work, I'm just wondering if its correct. If it is then the issue is probably in some other part of my code.

Comment: How are you using this regex? What is expected result and what you get instead (error/exception/result different from expected)?

Comment: you can try this one `^[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?$|1000$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use quantifier to allow multiple numbers:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(?: +(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ognZdY/1)

**Explanation:**

```
^                                   : beginning of the string
    (?:                             : start non capture group
        [1-9][0-9]{0,2}             : 1 digit from 1 to 9, followed by optional 1 or 2 digits (i.e. from 1 to 999)
      |                             : OR
        1000                        : 1000
    )                               : end group
    (?:                             : start non capture group
         +                          : 1 or more spaces
        (?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)    : same as above
    )*                              : group may appear 0 or more times
$                                   : end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$|^1000$

^ - starts with
[1-9] - first char [1-9]
[0-9]{0,2} - then 0-2 chars [0-9]
$- ends with 
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$ - numbers ranging from 1-999
|^1000$ - or 1000
```